# How to search a comma delimited column for a value of 1 or a 10 thru 19

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new to Pandas and Python.  I have a dataframe that has a column with comma delimited text values, like "1,4,7".  I need to define a new column (to be added to the dataframe) that searches thru this comma delimited field for a value of x.  For example, I need to search if there is a value of 4.  Sounds straightforward, but how do I write code to distinguish between searching for a value of 1 versus a value of 11, or 12, or 13, or 14....19.  Similarly, how to distinguish between searching for a value of 2 versus a value of 12 or a value of 22, or 23, or 24.  The range is between 1 and 24.  Thanks!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would split the comma delimited values into a list, make them numerical, and use a method of matching to the list.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try regex with `str.contains` or `Series.apply`

```py
val = 1

df['flag'] = df['col'].str.contains(f'(^{val},)|(,{val},)|(,{val}$)')
# or
df['flag'] = df['col'].apply(lambda s: str(val) in s.split(','))
```

```
print(df)

           col   flag
0        1,4,7   True
1    11,12,4,7  False
2  11,24,2,7,1   True
```

Comment: @BeRT2me Update the example.

Comment: @BeRT2me Forget to uncomment the second solution, now I think it is fine.

Comment: Looks good now, I had gotten `(^|,){val}(,|$)` to work in [regexr](https://regexr.com/6mq6t), but python's implementation wasn't treating it quite the same for some reason.

Comment: @BeRT2me Your regex worked for me:  `val = 1; df['col'].str.contains(f'(^|,){val}(,|$)')`  --> `TFT`.

Comment: Ah, I was using `match` instead of `contains`, makes sense. Glad it works!

Comment: @BeRT2me Yes, it's difficult to get from name that `match` starts matching for begining.